# Updating variable in for loop using oneliner

Tags: python

I am struggling with the following code.

```
def calculate_path_expressed_in_s(to_score: int, path: list) -> list:
   path_s = [to_score]

   for z in path:
      to_score -= z
      path_s.append(to_score)

   # path_s.append([to_score - z for z in path])

   return path_s
```

I want to update `to_score` in the commented one-liner. However, that output is incorrect. The correct output should be

```
[78, 50, 0]
```

for

```
to_score = 78
path = [28, 50]
```

How does the corresponding one-liner looks like? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a list-comprehension because there is a value that is propagated along the iteration, but `accumulate` can (it's a `reduce` which keeps the iterations)

```
import operator
from itertools import accumulate    

def calculate_path_expressed_in_s(to_score: int, path: list) -> list:
    return list(accumulate([to_score, *path], operator.sub))
```

---

With the `lambda` to understand it easier

```
    return list(accumulate([to_score, *path], lambda a, b: a - b))
```